# Read output from pipe line by line on windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, stdout

I have a c++ program that launches a new process through CreateProcess() and reads the stdout of the new process using a pipe created by CreatePipe(). I am using ReadFile() for reading the stdout from the pipe. ReadFile() function will read only a fixed number of bytes irrespective of newlines, but I want to read the output of the pipe line by line. I have seen this working on Linux but haven't found any example on windows ......

Any help will be highly appreciated....

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use c library's `popen()` instead? Then you can use `fgets()` to read lines of `fscanf()` for more complex parsing.

Comment: I guess popen() won't allow me to easily monitor the process state and its termination......

Comment: You will get EOF on process termination. Otherwise, you have to reimplement stdio's buffering OR read input byte-by-byte until you get "\n".